# How can I use other color stars in mobile Gmail?

Tags: gmail, android, webmail

In Gmail on my desktop computer, I can star an email with a variety of colored stars/icons (red star, yellow star, green checkbox, etc.) but when I access Gmail on my Android phone, using the standard Gmail app, the only color I can use for a star is yellow. Is there any way I can use the selection of colored stars on mobile Gmail as I do on desktop Gmail?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about an Android app.

Answer (score 1):

Same here.

I think the only answer for now is logging in from the Puffin browser. It allows for the full desktop experience.

Comment: Huh? Other browsers like mobile Chrome, with the "Desktop Site" menu option checked, work fine, too. If you check that box while you're still on the mobile version https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/[rest-of-url], you'll still be reloading that mobile version after checking the box. So after checking the box you still need to then go again to https://mail.google.com/ or at least delete the trailing "mu/[...]" and tap enter to be taken to the https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/ desktop site. (However, if you UNcheck, the box, the reload does automatically take you to the "mu/..." mobile version.)